# Erro ao serializar JSON em C#, aparentemente a API retorna estruturas diferentes dependendo do preenchimento do objeto

Tags: c#, json, .net, api

Estou tendo problemas no retorno de uma API de terceiro (não tenho acesso ao código) que estou consumindo, mais especificamente no trecho abaixo:

```
var result = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
var resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaymentDTO>(resultContent);
}
```

O erro ocorre no `return` quando eu deserializo o json `resultContent` no meu objeto `PaymentDTO`.

Este é meu `PaymentDTO`:

```
public class PaymentDTO
{
    public IEnumerable<ItemDTO> Itens { get; set; }

    [...]
}
```

Este é meu `ItemDTO`:

```
public class ItemDTO
{
   [...]

   public RecordDTO Cadastro { get; set; }
}
```

Este é meu `RecordDTO`:

```
public class RecordDTO
{
    [...]
    
    public AddressDTO Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

E este é meu `AddressDTO` :

```
public class AddressDTO
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Cep { get; set; }
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public string Complemento { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string Uf { get; set; }
}
```

O problema acontece no retorno da API quando o objeto de endereço muda, ele muda de acordo se a pessoa tem um endereço cadastrado ou não. Abaixo um exemplo de retorno para uma pessoa com endereço:

```
"itens": [
    {
      "id": "1193053",
      [...]
      "cadastro": {
        "id": "230009543",
        "nome_completo": "xxxx xxx",
        "endereco": {
          "id": "151032",
          "cep": "xxxxxx",
          "logradouro": "RUA XXXX",
          "numero": "777",
          "complemento": "blá blá",
          "bairro": "bairro tal",
          "cidade": "XXXXX",
          "uf": "SP"
        }
      }
    }
]
```

Agora um exemplo de retorno para uma pessoa sem endereço cadastrado na API:

```
"itens": [
  {
    "id": "879432",
    "cadastro": {
        "id": "43264",
        "nome_completo": "xxxx xxx",
        "endereco": []
    }
  }
]
```

Percebe-se que quando a pessoa **não tem endereço**, o objeto `endereco` é retornado como se fosse um array: `endereco: []` em vez de ser retornado como `endereco: null`, por exemplo. Mas quando a pessoa tem endereço, o objeto **não é** retornado como `endereco: [{...}]`. Quando a pessoa **possui endereço**, ele é retornado como um objeto único. Isso faz com que, na hora de deserializar, se a pessoa não tiver endereço, o processo estoura a seguinte exceção:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'NomeDoMeuAssembly.DTO.AddressDTO' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
> Path 'itens[1].cadastro.endereco', line 671, position 29. |

Porque, imagino eu, que o deserializador do Newtonsoft entende que o objeto `endereco` retornado é um array, mas não é. Então o erro me pede para que eu defina meu objeto `AddressDTO` como uma lista. Exemplo:

```
public class RecordDTO
{
    [...]
    
    public IEnumerable<AddressDTO> Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

Quando faço isso, o erro estoura logo na primeira pessoa que tiver o endereço preenchido, e a mensagem de erro é praticamente igual, mas dessa vez ela fala o contrário da anterior: pede para que eu defina meu `AddressDTO` como um objeto normal, porque o `endereco` retornado da API não é uma lista.

Já tentei tratar isso direto na propriedade `Endereco` do `RecordDTO`, expandindo o `{ get; set; }` para fazer alguma lógica, porém o erro ocorre logo no `get` da propriedade. Sendo assim, eu não tenho acesso ao parâmetro `value` que traz os valores do objeto a ser atribuído pelo dotnet.

Não sei o que posso fazer nessa situação. A última alternativa seria entrar em contato com os mantenedores da API para mostrar o caso.

Agradeço desde já caso tenham alguma solução.

Comment: *"O problema acontece no retorno da API quando o objeto de endereço muda, ele muda de acordo se a pessoa tem um endereço cadastrado ou não"*  um endpoint que retorna multiplos objetos? isso parece bem errado, um contrato deve ser respeitado e sempre retornar a mesma coisa

Comment: Pois é, isso é o que acho estranho. Não posso confirmar que os objetos são de fato diferentes pois não tenho acesso ao código da API, mas é o que parece. Ou o serializador tá inserindo automaticamente esses colchetes no endereço quando ele vem nulo. 

Isso ocorre tanto usando o Insomnia ou Postman quanto debugando o projeto C# consumindo a API.

Comment: Acredito que o correto seria você entrar em contato com os desenvolvedores da API que você está consumindo, pois mesmo que você consiga contornar esse problema, pode ser que amanhã ou depois eles alterem esse retorno por se tratar de um erro. eai você teria que voltar a mexer no seu código.

Comment: Se mesmo assim você quiser dar continuidade, tente manipular a serialização do JSON para ignorar array vazio. utilizando newtonsoft.json você consegue fazer isso

Comment: mas vc pode fazer um request por Postman ou curl por exemplo e confirmar como estão os objetos. Um endpoint só pode retornar um tipo, senão é uma *break change* em relação ao contrato, pode ser o caso de um cenário retornar não retornar parte do objeto (null) e outro retornar, se for assim estaria ok, basta pegar o contrato da classe mais completo... de qq forma, se alguém disponibiliza um endpoint, precisa ter um exemplo do contrato, e a partir dai vc consegue construir a suas classes

Comment: @MarcosJunior opa, eu tinha dado uma olhada nos overloads do DeserializeObject mas não encontrei uma opção para isso. Mas acho que se eu fizer direto nas propriedades do meu objeto, pode dar certo, vou tentar. Valeu pela dica.

Comment: @RicardoPontual então, eu fiz requisições pelo postman e insomnia, o retorno é o mesmo, como descrevi na pergunta e mais acima na minha resposta ao seu primeiro comentário. O restante do processo já está todo pronto e testado, só esse detalhe que ainda me atrapalha. A documentação da API é bem vaga.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução foi mudar o tipo do meu objeto `AddressDTO` para `dynamic`, dessa forma a deserialização acontece sem problemas.

```
public class RecordDTO
{
    [...]
    
    public dynamic Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

Quando o retorno do endereço chegava como `endereco: []`, ele era serializado com o tipo `JArray` e, quando vinha preenchido corretamente, era `JObject`. São dois tipos da biblioteca do Newtonsoft, que estão dentro do namespace `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;`

Com isso, foi só montar as validações em cima desses tipos.